# VLOOKUP and MATCH function to extract data from a table in excel. Can I use the same function across multiple cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup

could anyone please tell me if they see something wrong with this code? I've been staring at it for hours and I still can't see anything wrong with it but I can't drag it across the cells or even reword it to work for the others it is only working for the first column(Yr3).Any help at all with getting my head around this would be sooo much appreciated!

```
=IF($B$26="Thousands",VLOOKUP($B29,Assumptions!$C$4:$K$23,MATCH(C$26,Assumptions!$C$4:$K$4),FALSE)/K,VLOOKUP($B29,Assumptions!$C$4:$K$23,MATCH(C$26,Assumptions!$C$4:$K$4),FALSE)/M)
```

This is the part where I am trying to extract the data from

[image: []

This is the code I am using

[image]

And this is where I want to PUT the information. The highlighted cell is the one that seems to work but doesn't work going across at all which is my problem

[image: []

Comment: You need to add the third criterion to your `MATCH()` formula.  `,0`: `MATCH(C$26,Assumptions!$C$4:$K$4,0)`

Comment: Thank you so much!! I can sleep tonight now! Of course it was something tiny!!